# How to eliminate the flicker from this JQuery/CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do an animation using css3/JQuery while clicking the side bar, the current div slides to the left and disappears, while another div which was hidden slides in sort of like a  page transition.

this is what i've ATM : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8mRAM/8/)

HTML:

```
<div id='wrap'>
 <header></header>
 <div id='content'>
     <div id='contentMenu'></div>
     <div id='page1'>
         <div id='left'></div>
         <div id='right'></div>
     </div>
     <div id='page2'></div>
 </div>
 <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
html, body, #wrap {
   height:100%;
}
header {
   height:15%;
   background: #0080FF;
}
#content {
   width:100%;
   height:75%;
   min-height:75%;
}
#contentMenu {
   width:2%;
   height:100%;
   background:black;
   display:inline-block;
}
#page1 {
   width:97%;
   height:100%;
   display:inline-block;
   -webkit-transition:height 5s;
}
#page1 div {
   display:inline-block;
}
#left {
   width:50%;
   height:100%;
   background:#FF8000;
}
#right {
   width:40%;
   height:100%;
   background:grey;
   display:none;
}
#page2 {
   width:49%;
   height:100%;
   background:purple;
   display:none ;
}
footer {
   background: #58D3F7;
   height:10%;
   z-index:99;
}
.dis{
   display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Script:

```
$('#contentMenu').click(function () {
   $('#page1').toggle('fast', 'swing', function () {
      $('#page2').toggleClass('dis'); 
    });
});
```

but when the hidden div is given visibility, you can see a flicker in the footer.

- is there anyway to eliminate this?
- if i remove `-webkit-transition:height 5s;`, the div is animated from top right to bottom left ( `toggle()` animates height , width and opacity at same time) is it  possible to disable the change in height and animate simply from right to left?
- is there anyway to avoid the jQuery and achieve this using pure css3?

Any other ways to achieve the same using css animations also would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden` on `#content` should fix your problem :

```
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
    min-height:75%;
}
```

( [updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8mRAM/10/) )

Comment: Great and simple answer, could you explain why this is? Seems to still be prevalent in 2018.

Comment: This is what happened in this case :
**initial state** page1 is displayed, `page2` is hidden
| **1st click on the menu**, page1 is shrunk, hidden, then `page2` is displayed
| **2nd click**: page1 is extended, while `page2` is still visible. Since page1 and `page2` can't both fit in the container, `page2` is pushed to the right, and then pushed under page1 when there is no space left.
Adding `overflow: hidden` doesn't really fix the problem, it just hides all the elements that don't fit in the container. Since its height is fixed, `page2` is hidden as soon as it is pushed on the second row.

Comment: so to prevent this, would it be a better practice to chain the jquery animations so that one can't begin before the other has completed?

Answer (score 0):

I like the overflow hidden idea as well.  Also, you could get rid of most of the jquery by using css for the animation.  Using `transition` position the div absolutely outside of the div with `overflow:hidden`. Then set `.active` to  the position where you want it.